# Buffalo Router WZR-HP-G450H slow and unstable

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance, buffalo-router

I bought a Buffalo WZR-HP-G450H router.

**Problem**

8 device connected to it via wireless. When power it on, the connection speed is very fast, about 5MB/s while transfer files between a wired server and my laptop using wireless.

But when run almost 20 hours later, the speed is quite slow, about 50-100KB/s. Ping the wired  server, will get about 20% package lost, and response time various from 200ms to 2000ms. No one is transfer files at that time except me.

What's wrong with my router? Is setup error?

I have another Linksys router which setup is the same, that works fine for years.

**Network Environment**

We have a Cisco Switch, the router connected to the switch, and will act as an AP to extend the wired network.

I flashed the firmware to "Buffalo DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (09/27/12) std"

On this router, I switch off DHCP Server(we have another DHCP Server running), assign an IP Address 192.168.123.4 with Mask 255.255.255.0, and Gateway is 192.168.123.254, DNS Server is 192.168.123.1

In wireless setup page:

- Wireless Mode is "AP", can select "Client", "Client Bridge", "Adhoc", "WDS Station", "WDS AP"
- Wireless Network Mode is "Mixed", because there are some old device in our office.
- Channel Width is "40Mhz", because I want use 450Mbps
- Wireless Channel is "1"
- Extension Channel is "upper"
- Advanced Settings is "Off"

In Status page:

CPU

- CPU Model Atheros AR7242 rev 1.1 (0x1101)
- CPU Clock400 MHz
- Load Average 7%    0.08, 0.08, 0.05

Memory

- Total Available  94%   61428 kB / 65536 kB
- Free   71%   43528 kB / 61428 kB
- Used   29%   17900 kB / 61428 kB
- Buffers   13%   2344 kB / 17900 kB
- Cached   37%   6704 kB / 17900 kB
- Active   26%   4684 kB / 17900 kB
- Inactive   33%   5924 kB / 17900 kB

Space Usage

- NVRAM   21.38 KB / 64 KB
- CIFS(Not mounted)
- JFFS2(Not mounted)

Network

- IP Filter Maximum Ports 4096
- Active IP Connections   1%   61

Wireless Packet Info

- Received (RX)   100% 8406197 OK, no error
- Transmitted (TX)   100% 11504216 OK, no error

Wireless Status

- Mode is "AP"
- Network is "Mixed"
- Channel is "1 (2412 MHz)"
- TX Power is "25.5 dBm (EIRP av.)"
- Rate is "450 Mb/s"
- ACK Timing is "15µs (2250m)"
- Encryption - Interface ath0 is "Enabled, WPA2 Personal"
- PPTP Status is "Disconnected"

Thanks